# Extract all urls from preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on my code to fetch the href urls from the variable `$message` after when I'm fetching the data from the database. I have got a problem with using `preg_match_all` to fetch the href tags from the variable because it will display the array in the output like twice.

Here is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid [1] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid 
[2] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid [3] => https://www.example2.com/1340253724 [4] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid ) )
```

It should be:

```
Array ( [0] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid [1] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid 
[2] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid [3] => https://www.example2.com/1340253724 [4] => https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid ) )
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
<?php

$message = '<a href="https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid">Click Here!</a>
<a href="https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid">Watch The Video Here!</a>
<a href="https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid">HERE</a>
<a href="https://www.example2.com/1340253724">Example2.com/1340253724</a>
<a href="https://example.com/s-6?sub=myuserid">Here</a>';

//find the href urls from the variable       
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches);
print_r(matches);
?>
```

I have tried to use a different way like this:

```
foreach($matches as $url) 
{
    echo $url;
}
```

And also I have tried this:

```
foreach($matches as $url) 
{
    $urls_array[] = $url;
}

print_r($urls_array);
```

The results are still the same. I have tried to find the answer on google, but I can't find the answer for a solution.

Unfortunately, I am not be able to find the solution for this, because I have got no idea how I can fetch the href tags using `preg_match_all` to display the elements and store in the array.

The problem I have found that something have to do with the variable called `$matches`.

Can you please show me an example how I can use to fetch the href tags using with `preg_match_all` so I could store be able to store the elements in the array?

Thank you.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>` indicates the array nesting, not doubled output. Maybe look at view source instead of just the browser view?

Comment: PD of [get an array with a predefined structure using preg\_match or preg\_match\_all](//stackoverflow.com/q/13774097) or [php preg\_match\_all returning array of arrays](//stackoverflow.com/q/32797563) etc.

Comment: @mario Thank you, in what source I need to look at to find out where the issue is?

Comment: `print_r(matches);` is missing a `$`

Comment: @digijay I didn't miss a `$` when I used `print_r($matches);` to check for the results.

Comment: You aren't showing us what `$message` looks like. That might be useful information, yes?

Comment: @miken32 Oh sorry I have forgot to include it. Please see `$message` in my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wrote in documentation [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

> $out[0] contains array of strings that matched full pattern, and
>   $out[ 1] contains array of strings enclosed by tags.

So you could do like following

```
foreach($matches[0] as $url) 
{
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much for this. I can see the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $url) 
{
    echo $url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### *Hi,*

as far as I correct understand your problem is that u received one to much nested array with results and you cant read yours URL that are also as array?

One of the solution that u can use is getting rid of unnecessary nested array. You can do this by using PHP Array function `array_shift()`.

From [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it [...]

So the trick is that returned value will be your array with data through which you can loop.

---

A bit of sample with your case:

```
//from the moment when you use preg_match_all and have matches
preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches);

$urls = array_shift($matches);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    //do something with URL
}
```

Of course you can different use array_shift(), thats just a simple sample ;)

---

#### *Cheers!*